# Convexity of $f(x) = var(max(x, Y))$?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $Y$ be a random variable. Define $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = var(max(x, Y))$. Is $f$ convex?

Comment: If $Y$ isn't degenerate, in general it is not true.

Comment: Consider $Y$ uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for your comment. You're right. Can you put that as an answer?